# making facebook share/like plugin and twitter share plugin align side by side

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAjg5/) and I am trying to make the facebook and twitter to align perfectly side by side, but I can't because I think facebook does some relayout after the script is loaded. Can anyone help me on how to make this look nice and align them side by side perfetly. Here's some code:

```
<div class="row shop-share-items">
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.google.com&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=35&amp;appId=467928753241936" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

                    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-via="google" data-lang="id" data-hashtags="google">Tweet</a>
                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

                </div>
```

Comment: AddThis is a neat (free) service that will handle your social connectivity for you.

Answer (score 1):

Side-by-side? You can do this with floats :)

http://jsfiddle.net/sAjg5/1/

```
.shop-share-items iframe { float: left; }
```

Comment: You can do it with display inline unordred lists too, but it seems using divs and floating causes less problems. I've spent way too much time on social sharing buttons. I'm annoyed Facebook changed things recently. Google+ button also has advertised functionality that doesn't work in Safari...

Comment: I do agree with @stacey.mosier's comment though, [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) is pretty neat, and removes the hassle. Just not sure it has all the customisability some people require.

Comment: If you want to track the shares with Google Analytics you need to roll your own for everything but Google+. There are some WordPress plugins that do this. I always use the official buttons and just tweak and test...

Answer (score 0):

Add class to Facebook iframe e.g. `fb-share` then use below CSS

```
.fb-share {
  width: 135px;
}
.fb-share,
.twitter-share-button {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

}
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/sAjg5/2/)